# post request in android studio like curl

Tags: java, android, android-studio, curl

I have a question how to implement a post request in java in android studio if I have a valid request using curl:

```
'curl.exe anyValidUrl -d "911/21.10.2020/15.45" -H "Content-Type: text/plain"'
```

When sending data to the server, error 500 takes off.
Most likely I am sending data in the wrong form, where am I wrong, please tell me.
The function in which I am sending data:

```
{
    InputStreamReader isR = null;
    BufferedReader bfR = null;
    StringBuilder sbRes = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String strBody = "911/21.10.2020/15.45";
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","" + Integer.toString(strBody.getBytes().length));
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(strBody);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        System.out.println( urlConnection.getRequestMethod());
        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == urlConnection.getResponseCode()) {
            isR = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            bfR = new BufferedReader(isR);
            String line;
            while ((line = bfR.readLine()) != null) {
                sbRes.append(line);
            }
        }
        else{
            return (String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));
        }
    return sbRes.toString();
}
```